# Is Storybook's version of 'userEvent' sync or async?

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library, storybook, testing-library

I'm finding a lot of inconsistency around Storybook's version of `userEvent` (as exported by the `@@storybook/testing-library` package).  I cannot tell whether it's supposed to be sync or async.
In the [official docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/play-function), they even have examples that are both sync and async, like:

```js
import { userEvent } from '@storybook/testing-library':

export const Story = {
  async play({}) {
    userEvent.type(canvas.getByTestId('an-element'), 'example-value');
    // and later in the same example:
    await userEvent.type(canvas.getByTestId('other-element'), 'another value');
  }
};
```

The exported type definitions are mapped directly from `@testing-library/react` types, which are sync.  So my eslint rules are telling me NOT to `await` the result.

However, some of my tests sporadically fail when I'm missing the `await`!  So I think I should try to "fix" the types.  I just can't find any definitive proof that these methods are async and should be awaited.

Comment: When in doubt, look at the return value, if it's a `Promise` it's async and must be awaited, otherwise it's sync. It could happen that the return value changes depending on the parameters too.

Comment: All the methods share the same types as `@testing-library/react` (`void`), so it seems like they're sync.  But since most of the examples are using `await`, and some tests only pass if I use `await`, it seems like maybe the types are incorrect.  I just can't find any proof either way!